# How to Format Numbers in WinForms 1.1 DataGrid?

Tags: winforms

Is there a simple way to format numbers in a Winforms 1.1 datagrid?  The Format property of the DataGridTextBoxColumn seems to be completely ignored.  I know there is a [solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318581) that involves subclassing a Column control, and it's fairly simple, but was hoping there might be some trick to making the Format property just work.

Comment: I am fairly certain I have used the Format property successfully in the past. Can you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal opinion is that a datagridcolumnstyle is the way to go.  Without seeing the code that you have, I can't say for certain why your formatting isn't taking hold when no style is defined - but mixing in formatting with data calculations and other parts of the code can get very messy very quickly.

Creating a new column style class is very clean, and if you have to use the same formatting again in another datagrid, it's as easy as pie to reuse it.

Here's the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.aspx) that may get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I did subclass and it was easy and did work.  I still don't like it so much.  I was already subclassing column styles for other reasons.  I'd rather handle all databinding myself, where I can more easily change it and test it.  This whole mixing of the UI with the data is old school, and not in a good way.

Thanks very much for your answers, it's good to have second opinions.

Mike